# If I include 'Email Template' in Package.xml why doesn't it download?

Tags: email-template, migration, migration-tool

I am trying to use the `ant retrieveUnpackaged` call with the SFDC Migration tool to download some email templates.

I pulled the `package.xml` from the *Force.com IDE* and for whatever reason the `Email` isn't being downloaded in this call even when the following is included in the `package.xml` file:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```

Is this a quirk of the *migration tool*? Everything else is being downloaded except this directory.

*No errors are reported.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EmailTemplate does not support the wildcard operator; you will have to individually name each template. See the docs at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/daas_package.htm for constructing a project manifest for a complete list of which objects do and do not support wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Salesforce Package XML generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator) in VSCode to generate a package XML with all your email templates.

In the tool, select EmailTemplate checkbox, let it pull the metadata into the xml file, then copy then package.xml file to your clipboard. Save/merge that with your existing package.xml manifest, then retrieve source from org from the package.xml manifest.

Comment: Have been doing that recently-!